# Poles of the gamma function in the zeta functional equation

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

I doubt it is rigorous to derive
$$\zeta (s)=2^s\pi ^{s-1}\sin \frac{\pi s}{2} \, \Gamma (1-s)\zeta(1-s)$$
from
$$\pi ^{-\frac{s}{2}}\Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2}\right) \zeta (s)=\pi ^{\frac{s-1}{2}}\Gamma \left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)\zeta (1-s)$$
using Euler's reflection formula, since
$$\Gamma (s)\Gamma (1-s)=\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi s}$$
is correct only for **non-integer** $s$, so how can we assume all complex $s$ in the functional equation (the one involving $\sin$)?

Also, if
$$t(s)=\sin \frac{\pi s}{2} \, \Gamma (1-s),$$
then $t(2)$ is undefined, only $\lim_{s\to 2}t(s)$ exists. Doesn't this contradict the fact that $\zeta (2)$ exists?

It seems I'm missing something very important and would appreciate any help.

Comment: It is an equality of meromorphic functions, in the same way that $\frac{\sin s}{s}$ is entire or that $\frac{s}{s} = 1$.

Comment: $\zeta(z)$ is meromorphic, so where it converges, $\zeta (s)=2^s\pi ^{s-1}\sin \frac{\pi s}{2} \, \Gamma (1-s)\zeta(1-s)$ is valid. If it blows up near a point, then that point is a pole.

Comment: The Taylor series of $\frac{\sin s}{s}$ is equal to $1$ at $s=0$, but the function $\frac{\sin s}{s}$ is discontinuous at $s=0$. The function $\frac{\sin s}{s}$ is not entire, I would say. The function $\frac{s}{s}$ is an interesting example – when we plug in $s=0$, it is undefined, unless we cancel the s' – how can one say whether $\frac{s}{s}$ is entire?

Comment: Any analytic function with removable singularities is unambiguously extended there with the appropriate value, so yes $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ or for example $\cos(\sqrt z)$ are entire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In complex analysis :

> If $f$ is analytic (around $s=a$) with a simple zero at $s=a$ and $g$ is meromorphic (around $s=a$) with a simple pole at $s=a$ then $fg$ is analytic and non-zero at $s=a$.

You can call $s=a$ a removable singularity of $fg$.

Note I didn't write $f(s)g(s)$ (the quotient of two complex numbers) I wrote $fg$ (the product of two meromorphic functions).

Comment: The removable singularity $a$ of $f(a)g(a)$ means that $f(a)g(a)$ is undefined, only $\lim_{s\to a}f(s)g(s)$ converges. An example is $f(s)=\frac{s}{s}$, which has a removable singularity at $s=0$. Then how can we use the functional equation to determine $\zeta (a)$, but not only $\lim_{s\to a}\zeta (s)$?

Comment: $\zeta(s)$ is analytic and continuous away from $s=1$

Comment: So can we say that if $f(s)=\sin\frac{\pi s}{2}\,\Gamma (1-s)$, then $f(2)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$? Is it needed to evaluate $f(s)$ when evaluating $\zeta (s)$ from the functional equation?

Comment: At $s=2$, $g(s) = \sin \pi s/2$ has a simple zero thus $g(s) \sim g'(2) (s-2)$ and $\Gamma(1) = 1,\Gamma(s+1)=s \Gamma(s)$ implies $\Gamma(1-s)\sim \frac{1}{s-2}$ around $s=2$ (simple pole of residue $1$) thus $f(s) = g(s)\Gamma(1-s)$ is analytic and non-zero at $s=2$ and $f(2)= \lim_{s \to 2} f(s) = \lim_{s \to 2} g'(2) (s-2) \frac{1}{s-2}= g'(2) = -\pi/2$

Comment: Now I understand, thank you.

Comment: But what's the difference between $fg$ and $f(s)g(s)$? Both are functions. In the second one, there's just a variable specified. I'm not sure what you mean by the last paragraph of your question.